# React Wow is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wow.js

I am trying to add Wow.js to my react app. Here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/6y5185zj2w) to my codesandbox. I Have imported wow.js 1.1.2 and animcate.min.css 3.5.2. In my index.js I have imported animate.min.css

```
import "./animate.min.css";
```

and in my App.js I have imported and initaized wow.js

```
import WOW from "wowjs";

...
componentDidMount() {
    const wow = new WOW.WOW();
    wow.init();
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> _wowjs2.default.WOW is not a constructor

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Wow ! Do you have npm installed `wowjs`. I think you should assign like `new Wow()` only ...

Comment: @DavidJawHpan Same error with your update to the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import WOW from 'wowjs';

componentDidMount() {
    new WOW.WOW({
        live: false
    }).init();
}
```